# How to find integer solutions?

Tags: equation-solving

Following is the equation:

[image]

Need to solve for integer values of x,y when a,b lies between -1000 and 1000.
Problem is to find the number of integer values of pair (x,y) that satisfy it.

Comment: Have you tried searching the documentation centre ?

Comment: Assuming a and b are integers then the solutions are (a+1,b+1) or (a-1,b-1) for any a,b. This can be seen by rearranging (x-a)(y-b)=1. The factors must either both be 1 or both be -1. Noting when a=b=1 only (2,2) applies and similarly a=b= -1 the (-2,-2).  Mathematica is not required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reduce works in general. First, multiply both sides of the equation by `x y` to simplify, and then:

```
Reduce[a b - b x - a y + x y == 1, {x, y, a, b}, Integers]
((C[1] | C[2]) ∈ Integers && x == C[1] && y == C[2] &&  
   a == -1 + C[1] && b == -1 + C[2]) || 
((C[1] | C[2]) ∈ Integers && x == C[1] && y == C[2] && 
   a == 1 + C[1] && b == 1 + C[2])
```

This answer says, in words, to pick any two integers C[1] and C[2], set them equal to `x` and `y`. Corresponding values for `a` and `b` are then `a=-1+x` and `b=-1+y`. A second solution is given by `a=1+x` and `b=1+y`.

Accordingly, there are as many integer answers to this problem as there are integer pairs in the range you wish to consider.

Answer (score 1):

> Problem is to find the number of integer values of pair (x,y) that
>   satisfy it

Here is a way to proceed:

We'll use `Tuples` to generate the pairs `(a, b)` of `Integers` in the range we're interested. I'm just going to do this for the range `[-2, 2]`

```
Tuples[Range[-2, 2], 2]

{{-2, -2}, {-2, -1}, {-2, 0}, {-2, 1}, {-2, 
  2}, {-1, -2}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 
  2}, {0, -2}, {0, -1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, -2}, {1, -1}, {1, 
  0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, -2}, {2, -1}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}
```

Now we use `FindInstance` with the 4th argument (This tells *Mathematica* how many solutions you want found). Below I've requested a maximum of `3`

```
 sol = FindInstance[(#1/x - 1) (#2/y - 1) == 1/(x y), {x, y}, Integers, 3] &
 @@@ Tuples[Range[-2, 2], 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can then use `Length` to find how many solutions were found for each pair:

```
Length /@ sol
```

> {2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2,
>   1, 2}

Answer (score 0):

For each pair (a,b) you can use Reduce,

```
a=1;b=10;
Reduce[(a/x - 1) (b/y - 1) == 1/(x y) , {x, y}, Integers]
```

Then, use `ToRules` to convert to proper solutions.

However, this is probably quite inefficient and may take some time for all combinations of $a,b$.